# Making only specific parts of a string uppercase

Tags: python, regex

For a project of mine, I am parsing reddit comments and trying to make them uppercase. It works perfectly well with plain text, however with things such as links it creates bugs, making the characters in the link uppercase and therefore making the link unusable. Now links on reddit have very simple syntax, namely `[text](url)`. I would like to output `[TEXT](url)` knowing my comment will most probably have some other content.

I tried using regexes, but this doesn't work while I still think I'm pretty close :

```
import re

def make_upper(comment):
    return re.sub(r"\[([^ ]*)\]\(([^ ]*)\)", r"[\1]".upper() + r"(\2)", comment)
```

That regex is a bit messy (like all regexes ;) but still readable to me and I wouldn't mind explaining it if need be.

Input:

```
"blablabla (btw, blargh!) [text](url) blabla"
```

Desired output:

```
"BLABLABLA (BTW, BLARGH!) [TEXT](url) BLABLA"
```

Comment: What about doing a `str.replace`? For instance, you could do a regex to get the http link address...  Store it in a variable called `native_link_format` Then just call `.upper()` on the whole string instead of trying to pick certain parts to call `.upper()`. Once the string was converted to upper case letters, you could `str.replace` `native_link_format.upper()` with `native_link_format`

Comment: It was not clear at all to me, it sounded like the content would literally contain "(link)", to which I posted a perfectly reasonable answer suggesting a string replace and got several down votes for my troubles.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Guys, come on. It says this is for reddit comments. Use some common sense. This is about parsing [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) just like we use here at SO, and you cannot make assumptions that every user will include a link in their comments or not, etc., nor will links necessarily include `http://` at the beginning.

Comment: It's not fair to make an assumption that your readers know how something is marked up on a given website.  Accurate examples are essential, but even more so in a regex question.

Comment: @Jason - That URL markdown is the same syntax that's used here on SO.

Comment: I admit, had I gone to the Reddit site and looked at some comments, I would not have made that mistake but my point is I shouldn't need to go to another site to gather the examples I need to answer the question.  The examples included should be sufficient, the question should speak for itself.  I still don't know what `(link)` means, is that `(<a href="URL">link</a>)` or `(URL)` or `(description-of-link-but-no-markup)` or something else, it's not clear.

Comment: @JasonL. I saw your answer as you had it posted originally and then the revised version, which was similar to my comment. (btw, i didnt downvote). The only thing you left out was how to obtain the `%LINK%` variable that you used. I think if you reposted it with the example of how to parse the link and then do the replace, you would have better results... unfortunately what is done, is done, but a good answer could get the reputation back that you lost... and more :)

Comment: @JasonL. [reddit markup](https://www.reddit.com/comments/6ewgt/reddit_markdown_primer_or_how_do_you_do_all_that). This link shows the format that reddit accepts for links. Don't give up. I think your alternative would be good option to have listed for this question.

Answer (score 2):

This is the approach I took after some experimenting. I'm sure people will downvote me and let me know in comments if I've overlooked something just like I did to them.

### Step 1: The Regex

You were almost right here, but I would make it **non-greedy** so that it doesn't treat two links separated by non-linked text as one.

```
MARKDOWN_LINK_REGEX = re.compile(r'\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)')
```

Also, at least for the part in square brackets, don't assume there won't be spaces. People can link as many words as they want, even whole sentences.

### Step 2: The Function

```
def uppercase_comment(comment):
    result = comment.upper()
    for match in re.finditer(MARKDOWN_LINK_REGEX, comment):
        upper_match = match.group(0).upper()
        corrected_link = upper_match.replace(match.group(2).upper(),
                                             match.group(2))
        result = result.replace(upper_match, corrected_link)
    return result
```

First, make the whole comment uppercase, then make corrections. For the corrections, I loop over all the non-overlapping matches the regex above produces (`re.finditer`), <del>fix the link by lowercasing what's in parentheses, then make *that* replacement in the original comment string.</del>
As was pointed out in the comments, lowercasing a link will not always work -- the original case must be preserved. In the updated function, we loop over matches in the original comment (and thus the original case) to generate the replacement, adding it to the uppercase string we created at the beginning.

### Step 3: Testing it Out

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(uppercase_comment('this comment has zero links'))
    print(uppercase_comment('this comment has [a link at the end](Google.com)'))
    print(uppercase_comment('[there is a link](Google.com) at the beginning'))
    print(uppercase_comment('there is [a link](Google.com) in the middle'))
    print(uppercase_comment('there are [a few](Google.com) links [in](StackOverflow.com) this one'))
    print(uppercase_comment("doesn't matter (it shouldn't!) if there are [extra parens](Google.com)"))
```

Produces

```
THIS COMMENT HAS ZERO LINKS
THIS COMMENT HAS [A LINK AT THE END](Google.com)
[THERE IS A LINK](Google.com) AT THE BEGINNING
THERE IS [A LINK](Google.com) IN THE MIDDLE
THERE ARE [A FEW](Google.com) LINKS [IN](StackOverflow.com) THIS ONE
DOESN'T MATTER (IT SHOULDN'T!) IF THERE ARE [EXTRA PARENS](Google.com)
```

Please comment with feedback and fixes. Note mine is in Python 3 but the only 3-specific thing I'm using is the print function.

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  Down voting is generally unnecessary, good answers will naturally float to the top.  Down voting should should only used in extreme circumstances.  It's mean-spirited to down vote "good try" answers.  You're taking away reputation from the answerer.

Comment: @Jason - Good answers float to the top... and bad answers sink to the bottom.

Comment: Read the tooltip when you hover over the downvote arrow. It says, "This answer is not useful." For whatever reason (didn't know about reddit, didn't know about Markdown, didn't understand the question), several answers were posted here that were not useful because they made invalid assumptions. When I do the same, I get downvoted and sometimes end up removing an answer. It also costs me rep to downvote.

Comment: You set the `corrected_link` to lower case, but a link does not necessarily have to be lower case. For instance, here is a shortened link to this question. works: http://goo.gl/91grGQ. doesn't work : http://goo.gl/91grgq. So we can not assume that every link should always be lower case

Comment: Thank you very much! (I'm OP, don't know if some kind of flair will show up, I'm new to this). But as /u/Dan said it's important to keep the **original** comment and not give a lowercase version of it. and if you start by putting the whole comment in uppercase like you did, you will lose that information :/

Comment: You're both right, of course. A direct mapping of links to files like Apache does would also fail on a server using a case-sensitive file system. Corrected version in a moment.

Comment: OK, corrections posted. The corrected version is a little uglier (the reason I shifted the case of the whole string at the beginning was to attempt to flip the case as few times as possible) because we have to shift the case on a couple of the matched groups to make the replacement come out right. Basically it goes back and subs in the original case of the links over their now uppercase versions in the new string.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - Yes, it does say "This answer is not useful." when you hover over the down vote button but if you read the stack overflow help article, it explains how and why down votes should be used sparingly.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all of you, here's a combined version of all of your suggestions, that does everything I want it to :

```
def make_upper(comment):
    native_links = re.findall(r"\[.*?\]\((.*?)\)", comment)
    result = comment.upper()
    for url in native_links:
        result = result.replace(url.upper(), url)
return result
```

I'm not quite sure it's the fastest way but in the final algorithm this code shouldn't be used too often so that'll do, thanks again!

Comment: What about a comment like this? `A plain reference to google.com should not be affected by [this](google.com)`  You will get lower case text for all sub-strings that match your link text..

Comment: Good one. OK I could just cheat by making it look for '](url)', but there's got to be a better way. The best would be a findall version that gives me indices on where it found my regex so I can replace it afterwards.

Comment: FWIW my answer might help with this (though it may still have other issues) because I do the replacement right on the match instead of globally. In other words I transform `[TEXT](LINK)` into `[TEXT](link)` and then do a find and replace on that in the uppercase string. Whatever bot you end up with at the end of this I'd be interested to see!

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers rely on global search and replace to handle the solution.  This is flawed for the case where the URL for a link is also contained in the rest of the text.  A guaranteed safe way to do it is to construct the new string as you go along.

For example, while this isn't elegant, it does the trick:

```
MARKDOWN_LINK_REGEX = re.compile(r'(.*?)(\[.*?\])(\(.*?\))(.*)')

def uppercase_comment(text):
    result = ""
    while True:
        match = MARKDOWN_LINK_REGEX.match(text)
        if match:
            result += match.group(1).upper() + match.group(2).upper()
            result += match.group(3)
            text = match.group(4)
        else:
            result += text.upper()
            return result
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the case where "URL for a link is also contained in the rest of the text" occurs that your code will resolve?

Comment: @dan see my comments on toctave's answer.

Comment: Very good point if a rare case. Minor quibble: you seem to just rename your `comment` to `text` part way through. Maybe it did something in a version of this algorithm that got edited out? You're not treating them separately (any more) so just call it text or comment at the beginning and leave it. :)

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist - Yeah I don't imagine many people will hit it, but I've been bitten too many times by something similarly unlikely in the past to ignore it.